# NVD3 & IE Object doesn't support property or method addGraph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3 chart templates

when drawing the graph IE (currently using IE11) gives the error:

"Object doesn't support property or method 'addGraph'

the object it is referring to is 'nv'

on this code:

```
self.drawGraph = function () {
    var chart;

    var data = self.formatData(self.currentFits, self.controlFits);

    nv.addGraph(function () {
        chart = nv.models.lineChart().margin({ left: 200, right: 100 }).useInteractiveGuideline(true).forceY([-0.01, 0.01]).forceX([0, 120]);

        d3.select('#SpotRatesChart svg')
            .datum(data)
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    });
}
```

this is not happening when i debug on my local development server just when i deploy to the test server.

regards,

Comment: Different versions of NVD3?

Comment: no i deploying straight from my development server an not through any CI infrastructure. it's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

added the above and IE started behaving